# If my circuit is electrically isolated, do i have to worry about a polarizing effect on my sensor's output?

Tags: sensor, isolation, conductivity

If I am making [a conductivity sensor](https://publiclab.org/wiki/conductivity_sensing) one of the things it need to watch out for is polarizing the water.

easiest way to do this is have the output output signal of the sensor have a +/-0.2V square wave.

i was wondering if i electrically isolate the output circuit with an isolated DC-DC power supply, can i just have the circuit output a 0-0.4V square wave (or in my case a 2.3-2.7V square wave), since its floating with respect to the water anyways?

Comment: In order to be sure we understand your question, do you think you could edit it to add a diagram? The important thing is that the circuit be pure AC as seen from the perspective of the medium whose resistivity is being measured. So my first guess would be that, no, you can't output a positive square wave, and isolating the supply has nothing to do with it. But I may be misunderstanding your question due to lack of diagram. Make sure your diagram shows grounding details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the article you linked says, the signal should be "with a symmetric oscillation with respect to both electrodes (no net polarization)". Net polarization — an average DC voltage — will result in galvanic corrosion. Ensuring the average is zero means the corrosion reverses course perpetually and the electrodes will remain mostly intact.

Your proposed square wave has a positive average. Your isolated power supply is helpful because it ensures no current will flow between the sensor and anything else, but the sensor still needs to be symmetric.

In order to make a symmetric output,  use [an H-bridge circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge) to reverse the two electrodes. H bridges are commonly used for motor reversing and can be made of transistors or obtained as a single IC. Instead of generating a square wave signal that goes to an electrode, you would send it to the H-bridge to trigger the reversing.

Another way to make a guaranteed symmetric and isolated output is to use a transformer (at which point you don't need an isolated DC-DC either) but I don't know what effect that would have on conductivity sensing.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much but thought i'd make sure in case i could slice a dollar off the design with a cheaper DC-DC

Answer (score 0):

You can AC couple any square wave and detect the voltage across the electrodes.

THe resistive conductivity from ionic contamination is a “leakage” resistive  component.  The reactive and conductivity is from the fact that water has a dielectric constant of 80 relative to air.

Thus you choose the probe gap such that the R // 2pif C values are such that the 2nd term is a higher impedance than R  and can be neglected.  If not then you have to cancel this effect otherwise with a different circuit.

The 4 pin Kelvin Bridge method implies you want to drive with a current sourced square wave ie. a Voltage with a much higher Resistance than the load or an actual current regulated square wave that starts from say 1uA to 1mA. For a 60dB or 1000:1 range in output Conductivity R.  This eliminates the leakage for DC from probe corrosion but will not eliminate it if the corrosion conductance is greater than the water.  ( Since it shunts the water)

Probe gap in air can be measured and compared with water to prove this by measuring series current from a 5V logic signal  square wave with a 10Meg Z input type  DMM to measure Vac capacitively coupled. This creates a current source and thus the voltage reads V=I * R for R << 10M THe method you use to detect the precision envelope amplitude

Ideally I would choose  to attenuate harmonics and use a sine wave then a precision Op Amp envelope detector to detect full scale signal at a low frequency then control the current gain of a common emitter with high Early leakage resistance to make a variable  current source such that you measure gain with an OTA variable voltage controlled current that can offer you a 1000:1 range in conductive readings.  Cheap plant soil conductive meters do not have this accuracy or dynamic range.